# how to access elements of a list in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Entities

```
public class Employee
{   
    public long BusinessUnitID{ get; set; }
    public long EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public long InfoTypeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public List<ContactData> ContactDetails{ get; set; }
}

public class ContactData
{
    public string ContactTypeName { get; set; }
    public string ContactValue { get; set; }
}
```

Model

```
Public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public long BusinessUnitID { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeData> EmployeeInfo { get; set;}
    public List<ContactInfo> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeData
{
    public long EmployeeID { get; set;}
    public string EmployeeName { get; set;}
}

Public class ContactInfo
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public long ContactValue { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Update(long BusinessUnitID=2)
{
    if (Session[Constants.Session_IsAdmin] != null && Convert.ToBoolean(Session[Constants.Session_IsAdmin]))

    {
        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
        List<Employee> employee = GetEmployeeById(Convert.ToInt64(BusinessUnitID));
        List<EmployeeData> lstEmployeeData = new List<EmployeeData>();
        List<ContactInfo> lstContactInfo = new List<OptionDetails>();        
        var ID = employee.Select(x => x.BusinessUnitID).ToList();
        foreach(var item in employee.Where(x => x.BusinessUnitID == BusinessUnitID))
        {
            EmployeeData employeeData = new EmployeeData();
            employeeData.EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID;
            employeeData.EmployeeName = item.EmployeeName;
            foreach (var local in employee.Where(q => q.EmployeeID == employeeData.EmployeeID))
            {
                //ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
                //contactInfo.ContactName = local.ContactDetails.Select(p => p.ContactName).ToString();
               //contactInfo.ContactValue = local.ContactDetails.Select(s => s.ContactValue).ToString();
            }
            lstEmployeeData.Add(employeeData);
        }
        return View(EmployeeDetails);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting a list `Employee` in which i have below properties and a list `ContactDetails` which is a list containing atleast 3 elements for its properties. For eg 3 types of `ContactTypeName` and `ContactValue` as `Home: 000000000, work: 9999999, mobile: 8888888`. For a businessUnitid i got all employeeid for a perticular `EmployeeID` i want contact details but i'm unable to get or 3 `contactvalue` and `contactname`. In list `Employee` there is list `ContactDetails` in which there would be 3 or 5 contact numbers. I don't know how must i assign it to a list.

Comment: Can you change design of your models?

Comment: for things to work, yeah i can :) @MukeshModhvadiya

Comment: Why don't you add property for ContactDetails in Employee model? same as in your entity classes. Let me add details in answer.

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya thanks it worked. I just wanna know one more thing, is it possible to assign these retrieved value to `@HTM.LabelFor` control or any other controls in the view using **IF** and **FOR** conditions. As first i have to check businessUnit then EmployeeID and the ContactType

Comment: glad it helped you :) Of course you can use all data in html helpers with loops and IF conditions. e.g. @if (some condition){ your razor/html code here }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As employee can have multiple contact details, you need to add contact detail list property to EmployeeData class

Model classes :

```
Public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public EmployeeDetails()
    {
        EmployeeInfo = new List<EmployeeData>();
    }
    public long BusinessUnitID { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeData> EmployeeInfo { get; set;}
}

public class EmployeeData
{
    public EmployeeData()
    {
        Contacts = new List<ContactInfo>();
    }
    public long EmployeeID { get; set;}
    public string EmployeeName { get; set;}
    public List<ContactInfo> Contacts { get; set; }
}

Public class ContactInfo
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public long ContactValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then it's easy to pass the data of employees with multiple contacts

```
public ActionResult Update(long BusinessUnitID=2)
{
    if (Session[Constants.Session_IsAdmin] != null && Convert.ToBoolean(Session[Constants.Session_IsAdmin]))

    {
        List<Employee> employees = GetEmployeeById(Convert.ToInt64(BusinessUnitID));

        List<EmployeeData> lstEmployeeData = new List<EmployeeData>();        

        foreach(var item in employee.Where(x => x.BusinessUnitID == BusinessUnitID))
        {
            EmployeeData employeeData = new EmployeeData();
            employeeData.EmployeeID = item.EmployeeID;
            employeeData.EmployeeName = item.EmployeeName;
            foreach (var contact in employee.ContactDetails)
            {
                ContactInfo contactInfo = new ContactInfo();
                contactInfo.ContactName = contact.ContactName;
                contactInfo.ContactValue = contact.ContactValue;
                employeeData.Contacts.Add(contactInfo);
            }

            lstEmployeeData.Add(employeeData);
        }
        EmployeeDetails empDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
        empDetails.EmployeeInfo = lstEmployeeData;
        return View(empDetails);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```